# Get date or first lower date from database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, select

How can I find first lower date than given from database.
I need find date - 30 days than today date in database if this date not exist I need get first lower date than.

```
    2017-08-30
    2017-08-23
    2017-08-16
    2017-08-09
    2017-08-02
    2017-07-26
    2017-07-19
```

For example my today data is

> 2017-08-30

so I need find date -30 days from 2017-08-30

> (it will be 31.07.2017)

if this data not exist in database I need to take first lower date than 31.07.2017

> so this date will be 2017-07-26

I tried:

```
$lastMonth = date_format(new \Datetime('-30 days'), 'Y-m-d');
    for($i= 0; $i<7;){
            $parts = explode('-', $lastMonth);
            $lastMonth = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $parts[1], $parts[2] - $i, $parts[0]));
            $query = $this->em->createQuery(

                'SELECT sum(psc.score) / COUNT(psc.id) as avgscore, psc.date
    FROM AppBundle:PageSpeedScore psc
    WHERE psc.projectId = :projectId
    AND psc.date = :date
    GROUP BY psc.date, psc.projectId
    ORDER BY psc.date
    '
            )->setParameter('projectId', $projectId)
            ->setParameter('date', $lastMonth);
        if(empty($query->getResult())){
            $i++;
        }else{
            $date = $query->getResult();
            break;
        }
        }
```

This return me 2017-07-26 so its work but... this is not elegant way to do this I think.
I have a lot of query to database now. I think I can do it with one query. Maybe someone can help me and tell me how can I do this in only mySQL query without for loop?

Comment: What is the result of the current code?

Comment: current code return me what I need but it not elegant way I want to find more performance way like one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the trick, if I understand correctly:

```php
$query = $this->em->createQuery(
        'SELECT sum(psc.score) / COUNT(psc.id) as avgscore, psc.date
        FROM AppBundle:PageSpeedScore psc
        WHERE psc.projectId = :projectId
        AND psc.date <= :date AND DATE_ADD(psc.date, 7, 'DAY') >= :date
        GROUP BY psc.date, psc.projectId
        ORDER BY psc.date DESC')
    ->setParameter('projectId', $projectId)
    ->setParameter('date', $lastMonth)
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getSingleResult();
```

You basically search for alle results with the date smaller or equal to your threshold date (`psc.date <= :date`) and with the date less than 7 days older than your threshold date (`DATE_ADD(psc.date, 7, 'DAY') >= :date`).

You order the results by date in descending order (`ORDER BY psc.date DESC`), so the newest date below your threshold is the first record in the result set.

Then you call `->setMaxResults(1)` to only retrieve this first record and return it with `->getSingleResult()`. If there is no matching result found, getSingleResult will throw an `NoResultException` which you can catch and then use your default value instead.

Comment: ok it works fine but how can I secured this to loo forward only 7 days. If i dont find date 7 days lower than given date I want to return default value. How can I search only 7 days forward in this query?

Comment: Check my updated answer. I included the additional condition `AND DATE_ADD(psc.date, 7, 'DAY') >= :date`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whole loop and do this instead

```
SELECT sum(psc.score) / COUNT(psc.id) as avgscore, MAX(psc.date) AS thedate
FROM AppBundle:PageSpeedScore psc
WHERE psc.projectId = :projectId
AND psc.date <= (SELECT DATE_SUB(MAX(`date`), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
                     FROM AppBundle:PageSpeedScore 
                     WHERE projectId = :projectId
                    )
```

You only need one query and to bind your projectid

Since there's an aggregate function on all columns of the SELECT clause there's no need to GROUP BY

Comment: I dont know symfony at all. This is standard MySQL syntax. Can't you force the SQL instead of using a "creator" ???